# How to get data from asmx webservice?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, android-asynctask, asmx

[image: i]

I want to access the  name of customers that is in red color box, in the picture above, but it do not gives me data, it shows only "anydata type( )" only one time. I do not know what is category name, this is dynamic.
How to get data from this?

My code is:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(SoapObject result) {
        if (result != null) {

            for(int i=0; i<result.getPropertyCount(); i++)
            {
                Object resultObject = result.getProperty(i);
                KvmSerializable ks = (KvmSerializable) resultObject;

                for(int j=0; j<ks.getPropertyCount(); j++)
                {
                    Object subObj = ks.getProperty(j);
                    KvmSerializable subKs = (KvmSerializable) subObj;
                    Log.d("customer iiiii", subKs.getProperty(j).toString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: If you are facing difficulty in parsing the SOAP response then get the response in XML format which is much easier to parse using ksoap library.